# How to broadcast RDD in PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to broadcast an RDD in Python?

I am following the book "Advanced Analytics with Spark: Patterns for Learning from Data at Scale" and on chapter 3 an RDD needs to be broadcasted. I'm trying to follow the examples using Python instead of Scala.

Anyway, even with this simple example I have an error:

```
my_list = ["a", "d", "c", "b"]
my_list_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)
sc.broadcast(my_list_rdd)
```

The error being:

```
"It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an "
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an
action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, n
ot inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) i
s invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the
 rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I don't really understand what "action or transformation" the error is referring to.

I am using `spark-2.1.1-hadoop2.7`.

**Important Edit**: the book is correct. I just failed to read that it wasn't an RDD that was being broadcasted but a map version of it obtained with collectAsMap().

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to broadcast an RDD in Python?

**TL;DR** No.

When you think what RDD *really* is you'll find it's simply not possible. There is nothing in an RDD you could broadcast. It's too *fragile* (so to speak).

RDD is a data structure that **describes** a distributed computation on some datasets. By the features of RDD you can describe what and how to compute. It's an abstract entity.

Quoting the scaladoc of [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

> Represents an immutable, partitioned collection of elements that can be operated on in parallel
>
> Internally, each RDD is characterized by five main properties:
>
> - A list of partitions
> - A function for computing each split
> - A list of dependencies on other RDDs
> - Optionally, a Partitioner for key-value RDDs (e.g. to say that the RDD is hash-partitioned)
> - Optionally, a list of preferred locations to compute each split on (e.g. block locations for an HDFS file)

There's not much you could broadcast as (quoting [SparkContext.broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@broadcast%5BT%5D(value:T)(implicitevidence$11:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast%5BT%5D) method's scaladoc):

> **broadcast[T](value: T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Broadcast[T]** Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a `org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast` object for reading it in distributed functions. The variable will be sent to each cluster only once.

You can only broadcast a real value, but an RDD is just a **container** of values that are only available when executors process its data.

From [Broadcast Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner.

And later in the same document:

> This means that explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or when caching the data in deserialized form is important.

You could however `collect` the dataset an RDD *holds* and broadcast it as follows:

```
my_list = ["a", "d", "c", "b"]
my_list_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)
sc.broadcast(my_list_rdd.collect) // <-- collect the dataset
```

At "collect the dataset" step, the dataset leaves an RDD space and becomes a locally-available collection, a Python value, that can be then broadcast.

Comment: Nice answer but it's always essential to give the warning on using collect with large RDDs, specially for new users.

Comment: Isn't collecting this dataset the same as not making it an RDD in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot broadcast an RDD. you broadcast values to all your executors nodes that is used multiple times while process your RDD. So in your code you should collect your RDD before broadcasting it. The `collect` converts a `RDD` into a local python object which can be broadcasted without issues.

```
sc.broadcast(my_list_rdd.collect())
```

When you broadcast a value, the value is serialized and sent over the network to all the executor nodes. your `my_list_rdd` is just a reference to an RDD that is distributed across multiple nodes. serializing this reference and broadcasting this reference to all worker nodes wouldn't mean anything in the worker node. so you should collect the values of your RDD and broadcast the value instead.

more information on Spark Broadcast can be found [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html)

**Note:** If your RDD is too large, the application might run into a OutOfMemory error. The `collect` method pull all the data the driver's memory which usually isn't large enough.